# Filter emails that end with a digit while also filtering free emails

Tags: regex

I've created a regex to filter some email domains from my form:

```
/\@(?!(hotmail|msn)\.)/
```

This filters emails with domains of hotmail and msn successfully.

Now, I also want to optionally filter any emails that end with a digit. I created optional groupings. Group 1 checks for a digit at the end of the string before '@'. Group 2 checks for the domain.

Example of emails that are not allowed:

1. test@msn.com
2. test@hotmail.com
3. test1@mycompany.com

Example of emails that are allowed:

1. test@mycompany.com
2. test@gmail.com

```
/(?:(?!(\d+\b)))?\@(?:(?!(hotmail|msn)\.))/
```

This filters emails with domains of hotmail and msn successfully, but does not filter an example like test1@mycompany.com

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the pattern as:

```
[^@\s\d]+@(?!(?:hotmail|msn)\.)[^@\s]+
```

**Explanation**

- `[^@\s\d]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char
- `@` Match literally
- `(?!(?:hotmail|msn)\.)` Negative lookahead, assert not *hotmail.* or *msn.* directly to the right of the current position
- `[^@\s]+` Match 1+ chars other than @ or a whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qR2EzY/1)